# Setup Wai Middleware request logger to drop (not log) some requests

Tags: haskell, haskell-wai

I have an app where the Nginx reverse proxy is making a lot of requests to my `health` endpoint. I'd like to not log these at all so my output logs are smaller. I'm also logging everything as JSON using `Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger.JSON`, which has a function to format log messages as JSON.

One thing I *could* do is log an empty bytestring, but I was thinking there may be some way to no-op the log call. I can't figure out how to do that from looking at the various `RequestLogger` functions in `wai-extra`.

Does anyone have a recommendation for how to build a custom `Middleware` in order to not-log certain requests?

Comment: This might be useful: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filter-logger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a custom formatter in the following way:

```
-- | Wai Application Middleware logger
jsonRequestLogger :: IO Middleware
jsonRequestLogger = mkRequestLogger
    $ def { outputFormat = CustomOutputFormatWithDetails dontLogHealthEndpoint }


dontLogHealthEndpoint :: OutputFormatterWithDetails
dontLogHealthEndpoint date req status responseSize duration reqBody response =
    if B.isInfixOf "health" $ rawPathInfo req
        then toLogStr B.empty
        else formatAsJSON date req status responseSize duration reqBody response
```

This seems to work fine. However, I'd still like to know if there's a better way.